# XML file location is not valid in TestNG

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
"/private/var/folders/jz/bb3nbjgx3wj02jz3zwddn6n80000gn/T/testng-eclipse--1323985404/testng-customsuite.xml"
```

How could i replace this using my own .xml file?
[image]

Comment: Don't you have your own testng.xml file in your project folder?

Comment: Nops :), it seems i miss somthing.

am i need to save *.xml file in my project folder. Currently i saved in desktop.

Comment: Ideally you should include it in your project folder. If you have the TestNG plugin for eclipse installed, you just need to right click on the testng.xml file in your project folder and go for "Run as TestNG suite"

Comment: you just need to right click on the testng.xml file in your project folder and go for "Run as TestNG suite" –

didn't get this option "Run as TestNG suite"?

Comment: It seems you have not installed TestNG eclipse plugin. I assume you are using Eclipse. Are you?

Comment: yes, i have already installed TestNG.

Please check above i have attached image.

Comment: Your firstxml and secondxml don't seem to be .xml files. Please check that you create correct xml files.

Comment: now i have created xml file under project and right click on that doesnt display "Run as TestNG suite"

Check the attached image.

Comment: I have successfully created testng.xml file but while run it throw error "The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed."

Comment: What's the version of TestNG eclipse plugin you are using?

Comment: Finally i have done it. Thanks Abhi